# Python3, a lazy print

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing, lazy-evaluation, lazy-sequences

for my last project in Python3, i used a custom **lazy** generator to generate my data. Then use **imap** from a Pool (multiprocessing). 
So at this point, not any computation have been made.
The next step is to output the computed data on a file.
To do so, I either `print(list(data))` or `print(*data)` which causes the computation of the whole data (approx 1.5Gib right now, bit will grow fast), either do a `for` loop and print each piece of data, which do a lot of call to print (approx 10e6 calls right now, but will grow fast).

So, is there a way to make `print` iterate over a lazy generator?

Thank you.

Comment: Just call `print` in a loop. I believe the function call overhead will be the least of your worries.

Comment: If `g` is a generator then the code `for item in g: print(item)` *is* code which iterates `print` over a lazy generator.

Comment: that's the main lead, but i don't find it _nice_. Thus, whith a flush=False, this could be the best effective solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this recipe from the itertools docs:

```
def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)
```

You can batch the calls to `print` yourself:

```
for batch in grouper(data, 1000, ''):
    print('\n'.join(batch))
```

Comment: That's quite elegant.